# CMap lookup failing

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

I have an MFC application. It has a CMap which contains certain data objects, the map is declared as `CMap<DWORDLONG, DWORDLONG,_ItemsObj*,_ItemsObj*>` where _ItemsObj is a structure that contains various data.

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to search for an entry the Lookup method fails unexpectedly on x64 builds (and ONLY on x64 builds).

Here's the code I'm using

```
BOOL IsItemExist(DWORDLONG dwid)
{_ItemsObj* pObj=NULL;
if(!m_Itemsmap.Lookup(dwid,pObj))
{return FALSE;}
return TRUE;
}
```

Now this works perfectly on a 32-bit build of my application. However on an x64 build the Lookup always fails even though the items are present in the map and the key I'm looking for is present in the map.

I think its somewhat related to a build configuration issue, I have checked the linking properties and build configuration for both the x86 and the x64 option for the app project and they use the exact same configuration except for the target machine option (which should be different).

Can someone please help me fix this, I've been looking all over the internet for a solution but could not find anything.

Oh and I'm using VS 2010 SP1

Regards

Comment: Try looking into CMap.Lookup source... Maybe there is some magic there that disables it to work properly in your case.

Comment: Cant access the sorce.. Sorry, i tried it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five global helper functions that CMap, CList and CArray uses. They are CompareElements, CopyElements,  DumpElements, HashKey and  SerializeElements. Your problem is likely with SerializeElements which CMap uses to to store collection element.
The other thing to try is to declare your CMap as 
CMap < DWORDLONG, DWORDLONG, _ItemsObj,_ItemsObj*>