# I can Iterate through CMap but can't Lookup !DOH! What fundamentally is wrong

Tags: collections, c++17, visual-studio-2019, msdn

I feel this question is similar to:
[CMap lookup failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614572/cmap-lookup-failing)

Please, refrain from posting that std::map is superior etc.  In this case I'm trying to understand the arcane structure of the Microsoft CMap/Collection architecture and prove to myself that the reason I hate it so much is just because I don't undersand the pure genius behind it.  So please let me live in my fantasy world and humor me here.  I expect to learn GEMs of wisdom about template functions as it seems it's these missing functions that I have to properly implement to get what I am trying to do to work.

I have a CMap I'm trying to use:

```
CMap<CPoint,CPoint&,int,int> theMap;
```

I have also tried

```
CMap<CPoint*,CPoint*,int,int> theMap;
```

In both cases, I am able to fill the map and iterate through the contents of the map.  But I'm unable to do a successful LOOKUP on entries in the map.

I Understand how to make a CMAP solution using

```
CMap< CString, LPCTSTR, int,int> theMap;
```

Where I simply convert the CPoint to a CString "x:y" for a key.  But to me thats a hack for my lack of understanding how to build the appropriate template functions to use CPoint as a key.

But I'm trying to understand templated functions better and develop the proper templates for this particular case.

The first issue I found was that I thought I needed a HASH function.  I had difficulty with the "syntatic sugar" to get the compiler/runtime to actually use this HASH function:

```
template< >
UINT AFXAPI HashKey( CPoint p)
{
    #pragma warning(suppress: 4302) // 'type cast' : truncation
    #pragma warning(suppress: 4311) // pointer truncation
    unsigned long ul =(unsigned long) &p;
    return  HashKey(ul);
}
```

And at the moment, I'm considering the link above in that I need a Serialize function.  My guess is I have 3-5 bonehead errors and gaps in understanding I need to dig through.  If when I have rubbed my nose in it long enough I will hope to post an answer here.

```
template<>
BOOL AFXAPI CompareElements< CPoint , CPoint >
(const CPoint* pElement1, const CPoint* pElement2)
{ 
        if (pElement1 == pElement2) return true;
        if (pElement1 == NULL) return false;
        if (pElement2 == NULL) return false;  
        if (pElement1->x != pElement2->x) return false;
        if (pElement1->y != pElement2->y) return false;
        return true;

}
```

In debugging, I had one case where the hash was NULL.  I need to walk through more of the lookup function to see where I'm likely going astray.   But I was expecting that some of the experts out there will have some tips.

Comment: You say you are unable to do a successful lookup - what happens when you try? What outcome do you expect, and what do you observe instead? Show a [mcve]

Comment: Great comment, thank you.  I will revisit this and see if I can add some useful code that people can use to improve the question/answer.